# In Java when writing an array to file, only the last line is written

Tags: java, arrays, writefile

I am trying to write an array to a file using a loop, but every time I open the text file it only shows the last line. If I write the array directly with a toString it has the extra spaces and array characters I don't want. Here is my code for writing to the array

```
WriteFile data = new WriteFile(file_namec2g , true);
for (String s : full) {try {
data.writeToFile(s );
} catch (IOException ex) {
Logger.getLogger(CC2LevelManagerUI.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
}
```

Write file is my file writing class. I can post that in another comment if it would be useful. It is one I found on the internet.File_namec2g is the name of the file and the true is if it overwrites or not.
So my question is how can I get the array to print line by line into a text file that will show up as such in a program like notepad?

Comment: Are you re-creating a `PrintWriter` object each time you call `writeToFile()`? If so, that will discard all changes you have previously made without calling `close()` first.

Comment: Yes I am. How can I fix that.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2885173/how-to-create-a-file-and-write-to-a-file-in-java

Comment: For concepts - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/file.html . Good if you read complete "Basic I/O" in the tutorial ..

Comment: That worked, thanks for your help.

Comment: @NicholasHoffnagle Glad to know.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comment, you are creating a new `PrintWriter` object each time you call `data.writeToFile()`. Instead, create the object in the `WriteFile` constructor and then create a method in `WriteFile` called `save()` (or similar) that calls the `close()` method on the `PrintWriter` object. Call that method once you have written all of the text in your loop.

```
WriteFile data = new WriteFile(file_namec2g , true);
for (String s : full) {
try {
    data.writeToFile(s );
} catch (IOException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(CC2LevelManagerUI.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
data.save() // Save the changes to the file
```

In `WriteFile`

```
public void save(){
    pw.close(); // Replace "pw" with the name of the `PrintWriter` object
}
```